# Items in Recyclerview adapter jumps to right after i click a button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a scrollview as the root layout for my fragment and in that scrollview there is a linearlayout which inside has a constraintlayout and a recyclerview, and there are 2 columns in my recyclerview. When my fragment launches , The UI is fine but when i click on a button a column jumps towards the right side of the screen. im not adding any marginlayout to right or left so I don't know why this is happening. Didn't have this issue before, I am facing this issue after using scrollview. I have pasted the code below. Any ideas as to why the columns change after clicking on a button.

As far as I think, this is an issue with the linear layout because it was fine before I used that.

Fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="scoutingFragmentViewModel"
            type="com.resatech.android.navigationtest.viewModels.ScoutingFragmentViewModel">

        </variable>

    </data>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_bg"
                    android:layout_width="385dp"
                    android:layout_height="285dp"
                    android:src="@color/cpb_grey"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_scout_timer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:text="Scouting Timer"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:visibility="@{scoutingFragmentViewModel.mScoutingTimerTextVisibility}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_bg"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.474"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.335" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ready"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/connect_button"
                    android:text="Ready"
                    android:visibility="@{scoutingFragmentViewModel.mReadyButtonVisibility}"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_bg"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.484"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_bg"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_stop_scouting"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/connect_button"
                    android:text="Stop Scouting"
                    android:visibility="@{scoutingFragmentViewModel.mStopScoutingButtonVisibility}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_connect"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/connect_button"
                    android:shadowColor="#A84F4F"
                    android:shadowDx="0"
                    android:shadowDy="0"
                    android:shadowRadius="0"
                    android:text="Connect"
                    android:textColor="#140533"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.443"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                >

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</layout>
```

Itemlist xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout>

        <data>

            <variable
                name="itemGridViewModel"
                type="com.resatech.android.navigationtest.viewModels.ItemGridViewAdapterViewModel" />
        </data>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:maxHeight="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff">


            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/big_text"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="69dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:text="@{itemGridViewModel.values}"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.51"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.526" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/small_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:text="@{itemGridViewModel.description}"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.468"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/big_text" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="23dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                    app:imageResource="@{itemGridViewModel.imageNames}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.077" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </layout>
```

Display:

[image]

Comment: try add android:clickable="true" this line into ScrollView

Comment: Ok if i set my width = parent to linear layout instead of wrapcontent. i get that space from the start. Any ideas ?

Comment: because match_parent considered full with then wrap_content only view related with considered.

Comment: @AndroidTeam.. Ive edited the question with the picture. Can you please tell me how can i align both the columns with equal spacing from the left side and the right side. Meaning that the left column shold be on equal distance from the left end and right column should be on equal distance from the right end

Comment: @AndroidTeam Also if u can put that as an answer i will accept it. Might help someone else too. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add android:clickable="true" this line into ScrollView

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Try to used Recyclerview and set GridLayoutManger and define columns like this way..

```
        recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```

Comment: I'm doing that already, I figured out my issue . it  was that i had set it to 2 columns thats why the space was generated, if i use 3 columns the cards are displayed without any space like i want .